# How to use GNU parallel on Multiple Computers

Tags: parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I wanted use GNU parallel on my two computers. I was successful at running parallel on one computer, but  I was unable to run parallel on remote computer.

Version: Local: parallel-20140222 , Remote: parallel-20130522. I had enabled password less ssh login.

> `parallel -j+0 --eta 'muscle -in {} -out {.}.aln -quiet' < list`

But When I tried to run on remote computer "parallely" using following commands,

> 1) time parallel -j+0 --eta -Svaramesh@10.117.173.5,: -transfer, --return {.}.aln --cleanup 'muscle -in {} -out {.}.aln -quiet' < list
>
> 2) time parallel -j+0 --eta -S10.117.173.5,: -transfer, --return {.}.aln --cleanup 'muscle -in {} -out {.}.aln -quiet' < list
>
> 3) time parallel -j+0 --eta -S :,10.117.10.5 -transfer, --return {.}.aln --cleanup 'muscle -in {} -out {.}.aln -quiet' < list

All of them are giving following error

```
parallel: Error: Cannot open input file `nsfer,': No such file or directory.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Transfer has a double dash and no comma: `--transfer`

You may want to use the shorthand for `--transfer --return --cleanup`: `--trc {.}.aln`

And since you do not have special shell characters, you do not need `'` around `muscle -in {} -out {.}.aln -quiet`.

If you like `--eta` you might want to try out `--bar` too.

Comment: Thanks for writing such a wonderful program. I am saving a lot of time and work and using my resources lot more efficiently.

Comment: How to set set to use `/tmp` instead of remote's home-directory ?

Comment: If you like GNU Parallel: Walk through the tutorial
(http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html);; Give a demo at your local user group/team/colleagues;; Post the intro videos and tutorial on Reddit/Diaspora*/forums/blogs/
Identi.ca/Google+/Twitter/Facebook/Linkedin/mailing lists;; Request or write a review for your favourite blog or magazine;; Invite me for your next conference.

If you use GNU Parallel for research: Please cite GNU Parallel in you publications (use --bibtex).

If GNU Parallel saves you money: (Have your company) donate to FSF https://my.fsf.org/donate/